# Dart package fvm is failing to install any version

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

So the thing is I have activated the fvm package using `dart pub global activate fvm` and added Pub/Cache/bin to the path. I had also flutter, dart and git installed properly insalled. But when I do `fvm install stable` or `fvm install 3.13.0` all I get is this everytime:

```bash
 fvm install stable
Creating local mirror...
 Counting objects:    [██████████████████████████████████████████████████] 100%
 Compressing objects: [██████████████████████████████████████████████████] 100%
 Receiving objects:   [██................................................] 4%
✓ Clone complete
✗ Failed to ensure stable is cached.

Exception: Git clone failed

Please run command with  --verbose if you want more information
```

If I do with the --verbose flag I get:

```bash
fvm install stable --verbose

Argument information:
  Top level options:
  - verbose: true

Command: install

Creating local mirror...
 Counting objects:    [██████████████████████████████████████████████████] 100%
 Compressing objects: [██████████████████████████████████████████████████] 100%
 Receiving objects:   [██................................................] 4%
✓ Clone complete
✗ Failed to ensure stable is cached.

Exception: Git clone failed

package:fvm/src/utils/parsers/git_clone_update_printer.dart 80:5                      runGitCloneUpdate
package:fvm/src/services/flutter_service.dart 146:7                                   FlutterService.updateLocalMirror
package:fvm/src/workflows/ensure_cache.workflow.dart 73:7                             ensureCacheWorkflow
package:fvm/src/commands/install_command.dart 66:26                                   InstallCommand.run
package:args/command_runner.dart 212:13                                               CommandRunner.runCommand
package:fvm/src/runner.dart 233:18                                                    FvmCommandRunner.runCommand
package:fvm/src/runner.dart 115:24                                                    FvmCommandRunner.run
package:scope/src/scope.dart 151:12                                                   Scope.run
C:\Users\Samama\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\fvm-3.0.11\bin\main.dart 13:5  main
```

Here is the current folder structure of local fvm folder

```
ls -lha
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 glitchlover glitchlover 512 Feb 28 17:16 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 glitchlover glitchlover 512 Feb 26 20:39 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 glitchlover glitchlover 512 Feb 26 21:58 cache.git
drwxrwxrwx 1 glitchlover glitchlover 512 Feb 28 17:17 default
```

currently working with windows 11, fvm version 3.0.11, fvm doctor:

```bash
FVM Doctor:                                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project:
┌─────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Project                     │ pomoholic2                                      │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Directory                   │ C:\Users\Samama\Desktop\Code\Flutter\pomoholic2 │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Active Flavor               │ None                                            │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Is Flutter Project          │ Yes                                             │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Dart Tool Generator Version │ 3.2.6                                           │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Dart tool version           │ 3.16.9                                          │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ .gitignore Present          │ Yes                                             │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Config Present              │ No                                              │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Pinned Version              │ None                                            │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Config path                 │ .fvmrc                                          │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Local cache dir             │ .fvm\versions                                   │       
├─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ Version symlink             │ .fvm\versions                                   │       
└─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘       


IDEs:
Cannot resolve symbolic links

Path: C:\Users\Samama\Desktop\Code\Flutter\pomoholic2\.fvm\versions

Please run command with  --verbose if you want more information
```

flutter doctor:

```bash
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel [user-branch], 3.13.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    10.0.22635.3212], locale en-US)
    ! Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel [user-branch] at C:\Utilities\Flutter\flutter
      Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an official
      channel.
      If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions at     
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    ! Upstream repository unknown source is not a standard remote.
      Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to unknown source to dismiss this      
      error.
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.86.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I've stopped using fvm months ago, switching over to the faster and easier https://puro.dev instead.